# Accessing/Changing Parents State from Child Class using props (React)

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I am trying to set state of the parent class with the child. But having trouble figuring out how to do this. I've abstracted away anything I deemed irrelevant to the question at hand. The issue is that I am

```
Class Parent extends Component {
     constructor(props){
      super(props)
       this.state = {
         foo: "bar"
       }
     }
     coolMethod(n){
        this.setState({foo: n})
     }
     render{
        return(
          <Child coolmethod={this.coolMethod} />
         )
      }
}

Class Child extends Component {
     constructor(props){
      super(props)
     }
     componentDidMount(){ 
      let that = this;
       videojs('my-player', options, function onPlayerReady() {
         this.on('end',()=>{
           that.props.coolMethod(<whatever string returns as a result of 
           this method>)
         })
       })
     }
     render{
        return(
          // irrelevant stuff to this question
         )
      }
}
```

Currently this code gives me "type error: this.setState is not a function"

If you want more info on videojs: http://videojs.com/ (though this is irrelevant to the question by itself, other than the fact that I reference it in my videojs call in componentDidMount of the child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, tested working on my side, found two issues in the code

1. Javascript is case sensitive `coolmethod` is passed in to the Child, but you are trying to access `coolMethod`.
2. You need this > `this.coolMethod = this.props.coolMethod.bind(this);` in the constructor to inherit the setState function from the Parent, otherwise, `this` inside the `coolMethod` will be undefined.

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

   export default class Parent extends Component {
     constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
         foo: "bar"
       }
     }

     coolMethod(n){
         this.setState({foo: n})
     }

     render(){
         return(
           <Child coolMethod={this.coolMethod} />
         )
       }
   }

   class Child extends Component {
     constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.coolMethod = this.props.coolMethod.bind(this);
     }

     render(){
         return(
           <button onClick={() => this.coolMethod("aabbcc")}>1</button>
         )
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the 2nd class is `Class Child extends Component ...`. You need to bind `this.coolMethod` in your `Parent` constructor first.

```html
Class Parent extends Component {
     constructor(props){
      super(props)
       this.state = {
         foo: "bar"
       }
       
       this.coolMethod = this.coolMethod.bind(this);
     }
     
     coolMethod(n){
        this.setState({foo: n})
     }
     render{
        return(
          <Child coolmethod={this.coolMethod} />
         )
      }
}
```